# Checkboxthat check number of checkboxs

Tags: jquery

I added checkbox (class="checkAllBtn") that checked all the checkboxs in the page.

this checkbox is inside element with class "checkAllBox"

I would like to change it so it will mark/check **only** the checkboxs inside the table (or div) "checkAllBox" that "checkAllBtn" is in ( i have number of "checkAllBox" in the page)

```js
$(function() {
  var chkMain = $('.checkAllBox input:checkbox.checkAllBtn');
  $(chkMain).change(function() {
    $('.checkAllBox input:checkbox').not(this).prop('checked', this.checked);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table table-striped table-hover checkAllBox">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>
          <div class="checkbox checkbox-info">
            <input id="checkbox1" type="checkbox" class="checkAllBtn" checked>
          </div>
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div class="checkbox checkbox-info">
            <input id="checkbox200" type="checkbox" checked>
            <label for="checkbox200"></label>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="checkbox checkbox-info">
            <input id="checkbox200" type="checkbox" checked>
            <label for="checkbox200"></label>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: You have only class named `checkAllBox` which is on table not on div. Is this your correct HTML?

Comment: @ArunKumar - correct . I edit the post

Comment: This is invalid HTML. Duplicated ids

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The selector of your check all checkbox was wrong so there was no event handler attached.

I changed `input:checkbox.checkAllBtn` into `input.checkAllBtn:checkbox`
Also as pointed out by Tyler there is no need to wrap an element in jQuery twice. Therefore i removed the 2nd jQuery wrapper and changed the variable name to start with a `$` to indicate there is a jQuery object in the variable.

```js
$(function() {
  var $chkMain = $('.checkAllBox input.checkAllBtn:checkbox');
  $chkMain.change(function() {
    $('.checkAllBox input:checkbox').not(this).prop('checked', this.checked);
  });
});
```

```css
table,
tr,
td,
p{
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table table-striped table-hover checkAllBox">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>
          <div class="checkbox checkbox-info">
            <p>all</p>
            <input id="checkbox1" type="checkbox" class="checkAllBtn" checked>
          </div>
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div class="checkbox checkbox-info">
            <p>check this</p>
            <input id="checkbox200" type="checkbox" checked>
            <label for="checkbox200"></label>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="checkbox checkbox-info">
            <p>check this</p>
            <input id="checkbox300" type="checkbox" checked>
            <label for="checkbox300"></label>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <div>
    <p>This will not be checked</p>
    <input id="checkbox400" type="checkbox" checked>
    <label for="checkbox400"></label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Emm, no, still not working. One "checkAllBtn" checkbox still effect on all the checkboxs in the page...

Comment: @Roi Run my code snippet. You can see the bottom checkbox is not changing with the others. You probably have an error in your html structure.

Comment: This is invalid HTML. Duplicated ids

Comment: @MarkBaijens - I see....Where is the part that "tell" the script to change checkbox only in side the relevant "checkAllBox" ? Should you use "parents" and "find" comands?

Comment: @Cid, oops that was my bad. Lazy with copy paste. Fixed.

Comment: No worries, being lazy is part of the job

Comment: @Roi It is your own original code. This selector tells to only look inside that element. `$('.checkAllBox input:checkbox')`. This is basicly the same as `$('.checkAllBox').find('input:checkbox')`

Comment: @Roi w3schools has good validators for html. That might help you.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to affect the elements inside the table that contains the "check all" checkbox, then you can use jQuery to find the parent table element and only affect checkboxes inside that...

```js
$(".check-all").on("click", function() {
  $(this)
    .closest("table")               // find the nearest parent table
    .find("input[type=checkbox]")   // find all the checkboxes
    .not(this)                      // but not this one
    .attr("checked", this.checked); // set the checked state of them all
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3>Table 1</h3>
<table>
    <tr><td><input type="checkbox" class="check-all"/> Check/uncheck all in this table</td></tr>
    <tr><td><input type="checkbox"> Just another checkbox</td></tr>
    <tr><td><input type="checkbox"> Just another checkbox</td></tr>
    <tr><td><input type="checkbox"> Just another checkbox</td></tr>
    <tr><td><input type="checkbox"> Just another checkbox</td></tr>
</table>
<h3>Table 2</h3>
<table>
    <tr><td><input type="checkbox" class="check-all"/> Check/uncheck all in this table</td></tr>
    <tr><td><input type="checkbox"> Just another checkbox</td></tr>
    <tr><td><input type="checkbox"> Just another checkbox</td></tr>
    <tr><td><input type="checkbox"> Just another checkbox</td></tr>
    <tr><td><input type="checkbox"> Just another checkbox</td></tr>
</table>
```